# Will a laser with low power - operating as continuous wave - generate supercontinuum in nonlinear materials?

Tags: experimental-physics, laser, non-linear-optics, laser-interaction

Some nonlinear optical materials, such as for example glass doped with As2Se3 or As2S3, are able to generate supercontinuum if a single mode laser pulse, in range of a few watts, is launched into the glass. However, will the supercontinuum be also generated if a continuous wave of a low power (a few miliwatts) is launched into a nonlinear glass, and if so then will the supercontinuum affect the phase of the light outgoing from the glass, and to what degree. By degree I mean: no phase shift, a small phase shift of a few percent, a large phase shift many percent, or a self-phase modulation of the continous light, and at what threashold of power these effects will occur.

Note: The definitionof supercontinuum used in this question is any boradening of pump laser spectrum equal to, or greater, than 60nm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercontinuum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, I may be actually a good referent since my research is focusing on supercontinuum generation with CW laser sources.

I am still in the first year and starting some fabrication processes, but what I have gathered so far:

- A lot of my initial investigation is around the material from one of the top researchers in the topic, R. Alfano: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-031-06197-4
- Supercontinuum has a relatively narrow definition as "intense ultrafast broadband “white-light” pulses" (from Alfano, 2nd Chapter). From most of my literature search, since a good portion of supercontinuum generation is due to ultrafast laser pulses, which leads to spectral broadening and self-phase modulation under specific dispersion conditions.
- I looked a lot around in the literature and the best I could find (besides what is contained in the Alfano book) is that in 2006 Sylvestre et. Al. were able to generate supercontinuum by pumping several CW wavelengths and then engineering the dispersion properties of a fiber to match the phase of the multiple pump wavelengths: https://opg.optica.org/ol/abstract.cfm?uri=ol-31-13-2036
- Other attempts to do CW SC do it by using very high (400W) laser
- An alternative way to achieve this is by engineering materials to have relatively large nonlinear, high-order dielectric coefficients (in the form of $\chi^2$, $\chi^3$ and so on) which would more or less compensate the relatively low laser power with a higher nonlinear coefficient, achieving the nonlinear effects that would in principle occur at high laser intensities (SPM, XPM).

I am currently facing two problems in my research: Light interaction control and understanding the underlying mechanisms that would entail "supercontinuum generation with CW lasers".

In general I think additional open questions with CW SC generation is: Phase matching (otherwise how do you ensure that all the white light components are "in phase"?); If the white light generation is not through modulation instability (which is when the laser breaks down and forms pulses that then lead to SC generation.

> will the supercontinuum affect the phase of the light outgoing from the glass, and to what degree.

That will depend on the nonlinearities of your doped glass and how you manage to confine the light to increase the interaction length (as you know from the literature the interaction length in typical SC sources is by using very long fibers). I would, for example, consider how to on one hand control how the light interacts with the nonlinear material and how to preserve the light power (since there will be losses due to propagation, etc.).

To control the phase shift: You can also measure different fiber lengths output spectrum (maybe check if there are references in the literature for doped glass in CW regime), that way you can choose a spectrometer that suits the spectrum of the generated SC.

Comment: BTW, the definition of supercontinuum which you cited is just a definition of one author and not "the" definition. Other definitions say that any broadening of laser spectrum is supercontinuum https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercontinuum and the broadening does not have to be white light but may be in the infrared or UV range.

Comment: I agree that I used one definition and I am mostly trying to be careful with how I use the term because my research is also not entirely clear what the underlying light generation mechanisms are, but I guess it did not come off as careful as I thought, but you are right! Definitions are all over the place (imo).